# How to use a function to pass a control name for executing the same code routines in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to know how I can use a function to pass in the control name (in this case a Combo box)?

I have 8 Combo boxes, all of which are subject to the same code, so instead of duplicating the code 8 times and changing the name of the called combobox name, is it possible to pass the name of the combobox as a control into a function?

This is the code before I tried this method:-

```
private void cmbDataSetA_1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filenameExtension = Path.GetExtension(cmbDataSetA_1.Text);

            try
            {   
                // Clear combo before population
                cmbDataSetB_1.Items.Clear();

                // Make sure the data feed replacement media item matches the type of media (JPG/MOV etc)
                if (filenameExtension == ".jpg")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cmbDataSetA_1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string item = cmbDataSetA_1.GetItemText(cmbDataSetA_1.Items[i]);

                        if (Path.GetExtension(item) == ".jpg")
                        {
                            cmbDataSetB_1.Items.Add(item);
                            cmbDataSetB_1.Refresh();
                        }
                    }                   
                }
                else if (filenameExtension == ".jpeg")
                {

                }
                if (filenameExtension == ".png")
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR = " + ex);
            }

        }
```

Then I tried this following:-

```
// Call function with 2 combos (original and second to populate based on items in original)
PopulateCombo(cmbDataSetA_1, cmbDataSetB_1);

public void PopulateCombo(Control comboA, Control comboB)
        {
            string filenameExtension = Path.GetExtension(cmbDataSetA_1.Text);

            try
            {
                // Clear combo before population
                comboB.Items.Clear();

                // Make sure the data feed replacement media item matches the type of media (JPG/MOV etc)
                if (filenameExtension == ".jpg")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < comboA.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string item = comboA.GetItemText(cmbDataSetA_1.Items[i]);

                        if (Path.GetExtension(item) == ".jpg")
                        {
                            comboB.Items.Add(item);
                            comboB.Refresh();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (filenameExtension == ".jpeg")
                {

                }
                if (filenameExtension == ".png")
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR = " + ex);
            }

        }
```

..however, I get the following errors:-

CS1061  'Control' does not contain a definition for 'GetItemText' and no extension method 'GetItemText' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help would be great, please.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try changing  PopulateCombo(Control comboA, Control comboB) to  PopulateCombo(ComboBox comboA, ComboBox comboB)?

Comment: Ah hah, that worked - I needed to change public void PopulateCombo(Control comboA, Control comboB) to public void PopulateCombo(ComboBox comboA, ComboBox comboB) as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined ComboA as Control. Control is a 'generic' base class for ComboBox and doesn't have defined the GetItemText method.  If you are sure you will use combo box, declare them as ComboBox:

```
public void PopulateCombo(ComboBox comboA, ComboBox comboB)
```

Or include some type checking code like:

```
if (comboA is ComboBox && comboB is ComboBox)
{
    //your code
}
else
{
     throw new InvalidArgumentException(); //or alternative code for other control types
}
```